# Reference request for Rothenberg Steenrod Spectral Sequence

Tags: reference-request

I am trying to learn about the Rothenberg Steenrod Spectral Sequence. I wanted some references for notes, papers, or books. I especially want to see some examples. I found Niel Stricklands notes, which are nice, but brief.

Comment: Would you share a link to the Stricklands notes?

Comment: @draks... I guess, https://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/bestiary/ss.pdf